Evaluate $ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \ln \frac{6x^2 + 2x + 1}{6x^2 - 2x + 1} \, dx, $
To solve the integral
$$
I = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \ln \frac{6x^2 + 2x + 1}{6x^2 - 2x + 1} \, dx,
$$
use a substitution to simplify the expression consider the substitution:
$
x = \sin(t).
$
Then, as $x$ runs from $-1$ to $1$, $t$ runs from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The differential changes as follows:
$
dx = \cos(t) \, dt.
$
using $x = \sin(t)$:
Finally, the integral transforms into:
$$
I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sin(t)}  \sqrt{\frac{1+\sin(t)}{1-\sin(t)}}  \ln \frac{6\sin^2(t) + 2\sin(t) + 1}{6\sin^2(t) - 2\sin(t) + 1} \cos(t) \, dt.
$$
Simplifying
$$
I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\csc(t) - 1} + 1} \csc(t) \ln \frac{6\sin^2(t) + 2\sin(t) + 1}{6\sin^2(t) - 2\sin(t) + 1} \cos(t) \, dt.
$$
Note that: I am aware that there is a generalization, but I would like to evaluate the integral using trigonometric substitution, so I prefer not to use that generalization.

See this and see the comments in here
